# Custom file system implementation in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am researching a way of implementing a simple file system UI. The requirement is that I have an in-memory tree (custom data structure), similar to a file system. But this is not the real file system of the computer. So, I want to represent this internal implementation to the user to react with that like adding new files, deleting files, editing files, adding folders, i.e. the basic operations.

I have no idea how to achieve this using Qt UIs. Is that a good idea to represent these files/folders using `QLabel` and setting pixmap for them?
If I implement it like this, it is lot of work, like, once the folder is clicked, the frame should be cleared and the new set of labels should be loaded in the same frame.

What will be the easiest way?

Comment: you should use qt model view framework. There is a filesystem model, that you may derive from.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I couldn't find a good example code to understand it :( is there a recommended code somewhere I can go thru?

Comment: This video might be convenient for you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92biLZST6Vg. It basically explains how to build your own [QFileSystemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html).

Comment: Thanks for the video :) but looks QFileSystemModel can only explore the existing file system in the computer. But I want to code a custom filesystem for the in-memory tree in my program :(